# oily or fatty when talk about a meat dish

Tags: word-choice

I like German dishes, but for me it have a bit too much oil.
How can I express that?

What comes up to my mind was:

> "I like German dishes, but it's a bit oily/fatty."

I'm not sure which word is good for the food. Maybe both wrong?

Comment: It could depend on whether you're describing the meat itself or the method of cooking.  The meat is fatty, the preparation is oily or greasy, though we do speak of "oily fish" to describe the meat of the fish itself, separate from its mode of preparation.

Comment: I'm curious about which dishes now, but that would be an [Seasoned Advice SE](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/) question.

Comment: *I like German dishes, but **they're** a bit (greasy/fatty).*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would say  the food is **too greasy**. There may be regional or dialect variations, but British speakers would understand that.

Answer (score 0):

It's perfectly fine to use 'oily' with food. eg. 'This type of cuisine consists of oily food'. Fatty sounds a bit off but oily is correct and goes well with what you're trying to say.